# How do I access sprite meta data in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, editor, sprite

I am using Unity's native sprite editor to slice up a texture as a spritesheet.  I would like to be able to then get an array of all the sprite slice via scripting.

For example I would like to have a SpriteSheet class that could be used like this.

```
class MyClass
    // Drag sprite sheet from assets to this inspector slot.
    public SpriteSheet spritesheet;

    void Awake() {
        foreach(Sprite sprite in spritesheet.sprites) {
            ... do something with sprite
        }
    }
}
```

But it seems that the sprite sheet is nothing more than a Texture2D with a .meta associated with it.  There is a TextureImporter class that has a spritesheet property but how do I access the TextureImporter during runtime?  Even if I could access during EditTime I could use it to populate a Sprite[] which right now is being maintained by hand, which is painful for hundreds of sprites.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You might have more luck asking this on the [GameDev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Have a look at Resources.LoadAll... I think I understand your question... Then again, maybe not lol...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have a reference to a texture 2d:

```
Texture2D texture = ...;
```

you could do something like this:

```
string path = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(texture);
TextureImporter ti = AssetImporter.GetAtPath(path) as TextureImporter;
ti.isReadable = true;
List < SpriteMetaData > newData = new List < SpriteMetaData > ();
for (int i = 0; i < ti.spritesheet.Length; i++) {
  SpriteMetaData d = ti.spritesheet[i];

  //do whatever you want with the metadata...

  newData.Add(d);
}
ti.spritesheet = newData.ToArray();
AssetDatabase.ImportAsset(path, ImportAssetOptions.ForceUpdate);
```

this is a portion of a script posted [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/761009/unity2d-sprite-editor-multiple-pivot-point-edit.html).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are trying to do.
It looks like you are trying to do something from within a Monobehavior.

```
class MyClass
{
    // Drag sprite sheet from assets to this inspector slot.
    public Sprite[] sprites;

    void Awake() {
        foreach(Sprite sprite in sprites) {
            ... do something with sprite
        }
    }
}
```

If you are wanting to modify the sprites in the texture in code you should do it in an Editor Script. The solutions provided here will work but if you are using newer versions of Unity i.e 2022.2 or newer Property 'UnityEditor.TextureImporter.spritesheet' is obsolete: Support for accessing sprite meta data through spritesheet has been removed. You should be using the ISpriteEditorDataProvider

Code taken from https://docs.unity3d.com/2022.2/Documentation/Manual/Sprite-data-provider-api.html

```
public class SpriteSheetProcessor : AssetPostprocessor
{
    private void OnPreprocessTexture()
    {
        var textureImporter = (TextureImporter)assetImporter;
        
        textureImporter.textureType = TextureImporterType.Sprite;
        textureImporter.mipmapEnabled = false;
        textureImporter.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;
        textureImporter.spritePixelsPerUnit = 8;
        textureImporter.spriteImportMode = SpriteImportMode.Multiple;
        var factory = new SpriteDataProviderFactories();
        factory.Init();
        var dataProvider = factory.GetSpriteEditorDataProviderFromObject(assetImporter);
        dataProvider.InitSpriteEditorDataProvider();

        /* Use the data provider */
        CreateSprites(dataProvider);
        // or
        SetPivot(dataProvider)

        // Apply the changes made to the data provider
        dataProvider.Apply();
        
        // Reimport the asset to have the changes applied
        textureImporter.SaveAndReimport();
    }

    CreateNewSprites(ISpriteEditorDataProvider dataProvider)
    {
         var spriteRects = dataProvider.GetSpriteRects().ToList();
        if (spriteRects.Count >= 2) return;
        var spriteNameFileIdDataProvider = dataProvider.GetDataProvider<ISpriteNameFileIdDataProvider>();
        var nameFileIdPairs = new List<SpriteNameFileIdPair>();
            
        var spriteIndex = 0;
        spriteRects = new List<SpriteRect>();
            
        for (var x = 0; x < width; x += 8)
        {
            for (var y = 0; y < height; y += 8)
            {
                var sprite = new SpriteRect
                {
                    name = $"{textureImporter.name}_{spriteIndex++}",
                    spriteID = GUID.Generate(),
                    rect = new Rect(x, y, 8, 8),
                    alignment = SpriteAlignment.Center
                };
                    
                spriteRects.Add(sprite);
                // Register the new Sprite Rect's name and GUID with the ISpriteNameFileIdDataProvider
                nameFileIdPairs.Add(new SpriteNameFileIdPair(sprite.name, sprite.spriteID));
            }
        }
            
        dataProvider.SetSpriteRects(spriteRects.ToArray());
        spriteNameFileIdDataProvider.SetNameFileIdPairs(nameFileIdPairs);
    }

    private void void SetPivot(ISpriteEditorDataProvider dataProvider)
    {
        // Get all the existing Sprites
        var spriteRects = dataProvider.GetSpriteRects();

        // Loop over all Sprites and update the pivots
        foreach (var rect in spriteRects)
        {
            rect.pivot = new Vector2(0.1f, 0.2f);
            rect.alignment = SpriteAlignment.Custom;
        }

        // Write the updated data back to the data provider
        dataProvider.SetSpriteRects(spriteRects);
 }
}
```

Or you can use https://docs.unity3d.com/2022.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath.html or
https://docs.unity3d.com/2022.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetRepresentationsAtPath.html

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps not answering your specific question about the built in sprite sheets, but I use TexturePacker (from CodeAndWeb). They export a config file that allows you to get sprite information similar to what you're asking as well as providing a simple importer that you can work with if you don't need too much control.